# Spring Data JPA Distinct - Return results from a single column

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have some data that contains a `STATE` field (String/Text) that defines what state a given request is currently in (e.g. pending, approved denied etc.) and to get all the unique values from that column I can run the following TSQL query

`SELECT DISTINCT STATE FROM CALLOUT_REQUEST`

where `CALLOUT_REQUEST` is my table name and `STATE` being the field which returns something like:

STATE

- approved
- denied
- pending
- ...

However I don't understand how I would turn that into a query in my repository as it seems I need a "by" statement or some other filter mechanism which i can get the `STATE` based on?

What I am looking to return - as shown in the raw TSQL query above - is some kind of List or Array object which contains all the unique/distinct values in all of the `STATE` fields.

So in pseudo code i think i am looking for something like this:

`String[] states = repository.findDisinctState();`

where `findDistinctState()` would then return an array of sorts.

Hope that makes sense - I am very new to Java and Spring in general so I think I am missing some conceptual knowledge to utilise the above.

**UPDATE:**

The 'state' concept is closed so i could implement that as an enum - only problem is i dont know how to do that :) Ill look into how i can do that as i think it fits perfectly with what i am trying to achieve.

The List i get from the query provided is intended to be used to get a count of all the occurrences. I had this code before to get a total count for each of the 'states':

```
Map stats = new HashMap();
String[] states = {"approved", "denied", "pending", "deactivated"};
for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
    stats.put(states[i], repository.countByState(states[i]));
}
```

Am i correct in understanding that the states `Array` that i have in the above code snippet could be turned into an enum and then i dont even need the custom `@Query` anymore?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If that `state` concept is closed - you know its possible set of values - it should be an enum.

After that you can [create queries](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) that you invoke like:

```
repository.findByState(State.APPROVED)
```

If you can't create an enum, you need a separate method to get the distinct values, which can't be provided by JPA, because you need a list of strings and not a list of `CalloutRequest`s.
Then you need to specify a query manually like:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT State FROM CALLOUT_REQUEST")
List<String> findDistinctStates();
```

Comment: I have updated the question with why i asked for the custom query initially to show that i need to use it to gather a count of the Distinct values returned.

Comment: I don't see the issue creating an enum. Just create one with all the possible values: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html
Then create a field under `CalloutRequest` of that enum type. Finally, annotate it with: @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/README.html

Comment: The fact that this is my first Java application is the issue, i simply didn't know how to do it, but thank you for clarifying.

Comment: That's fine. If you need help I can send you an example

Comment: This didn't work for me, I get the error `Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class java.lang.String`. Apparently, you can't return a list of strings from the repository.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a JPQL query for this, with the `@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query` annotation:

```
@Query("select distinct state from CalloutRequest")
List<String> findDistinctStates();
```

Comment: This answer is correct as well as it does answer the headline of my question. My reason for marking @Luis Soares answer as the correct one was only due to the fact that he expanded upon the solution and provided guidance on the enum approach.
Thank you -

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use @Query then one solution is there to create an interface "StateOnlyInterface" with method named "getState()".

Then create method in your repo with name, getDistinctState(). Return type of this method to be kept as ArrayList of StateOnlyInterface.